# Don't show output when I require a library

Tags: r

When I require a library, I don't want all the extra output that goes with it. How can I turn this off?

Has output (bad):

```
> require('forecast')
Loading required package: forecast
Loading required package: zoo

Attaching package: ‘zoo’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    as.Date, as.Date.numeric

Loading required package: timeDate
This is forecast 5.4 
>
```

Doesn't have output (good):

```
> require('forecast')
>
```

Comment: `?library` tells you to use `suppressPackageStartupMessages`. What's wrong with that?

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich - further down it says, regarding `suppressPackageStartupMessages`, *this will suppress all messages from R itself but not necessarily all those from package authors.*

Comment: @RichardScriven: that's because package authors may use something other than `message` when their package is loaded, in which case your solution wouldn't suppress them either. `suppressPackageStartupMessages` works fine in the OP's example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap `require` (and/or `library`) with `suppressMessages` ,

```
suppressMessages(require(forecast))
```

and the messages won't appear when loading.